# NCurses over Mosh, altcharset

Tags: console, ncurses, mosh

The simplest program that should draw a horizontal line:

```
int main()  
{ initscr(); for (int i=0;i<10;i++) addch(ACS_HLINE); getch(); endwin(); }
```

works ok localy, but over MOSH connection result is qqqqqqqqqq.

I tested other well known ncurses programs this way (over MOSH connection) and some of them works well, like: alsamixer, vim, tmux... but other tested also showed "ugly characters", like: tetris game (bastet), dialog (showing dialogs from shell scripts).

So the problem again for myprogram above, tetris, dialog and others is:

- it works localy in xterm and virtual-terminals(term=linux) and tmux/screen.
- it works well over SSH too.
- it shows q and x characters instead of lines over MOSH client

Mosh is very usefull program that resolves ssh disconnections on laptop wifi. It creates its own terminal and sets TERM variable to xterm. Right before starting program over mosh, TERM var is 'xterm', locale command shows LANG=en_US.UTF8,LC_ALL="", fonts seems ok (and same results with testing different fonts)

Does someone know how to solve or further debug this problem?

Simplest simulation:

```
sudo apt-get install mosh bastet    #<--install mosh and tetris
bastet                              #<--tetris works ok
mosh -- 127.0.0.1 bastet            #<--q and x chars instead of lines
```

Answer (score 2):

It's in the ncurses manual page: the environment [**`NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS) can be set to inform it that the terminal does not recognize the VT100-style line-drawing codes used.  Also, the `U8` capability in the terminal description (used with `TERM=tmux` for example) tells it the same thing.

There is an up-to-date terminal description for [`mosh`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Mosh) in the ncurses terminal database.  On reviewing it, there are problems beyond line-drawing.

Comment: Ok, maybe that helps in some situations. For this one not for sure.

Answer (score 0):

After analyse of source code of alsamixer (that works well), finding out that this line is very important:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

as mantioned in [c library documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-the-Locale.html). Without it 'C' locale is default.

So my program now behaves well over MOSH too:

```
{ setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); initscr(); ... draw lines ... getch(); endwin(); }
```

But I will accept any other answer that solve it outside of a program. Like how to force tetris to do this without source-code changing.